# Why are functions of semimartingales again semimartingales?

Tags: martingales, stochastic-analysis

I am trying to prove the Itō's lemma, and need to show that if $X$ is a semimartingale and $f$ is a $\mathcal{C}^2$-function, then $f(X_t)$ is again a semimartingale.

How do I do that? I cannot see how to decompose $f(X)$ into a martingale and a process of bounded variation (even for $f(x) = x^2$ this gets tedious).
Or is there some kind of completeness result that ensures the existence of a decomposition?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to prove this before proving Itô's formula? Because, usually, this is obtained as an easy corollary of Itô's formula.

Comment: The proofs I have here use integration by parts to show that if Itō's formula holds for functions $f(X_t), g(X_t)$, then it also holds for the product $fg(X_t)$. (And therefore Itō's formula holds for all polynomials, and, by approximation, for all $\mathcal{C}^2$ functions).

But the integration by parts-formula only works if $f(X_t), g(X_t)$ are semimartingales, right? Otherwise I don't even know how to define a stochastic integral.